# Converting list of date-time strings to list of DateTime values

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, iso8601

I'm brand-new to C#.  Using SharpDevelop program.  I can convert a ISO 8601 DateTime value within a 'for' loop.  I am sure that the ToList method of 'records' would allow me to convert all the string entries to DateTime values, but I can't get there.  Please help.

```
var myFormat = string.Empty;
myFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
var myDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
var originTime = new System.DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
var mySpan = myDateTime.Subtract(new System.DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0));
var value = mySpan.TotalSeconds;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.csv"))
{
    var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
    IEnumerable<DataRecord1> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord1>();
    foreach (DataRecord1 record in records.Take(5)) 
    {
        myDateTime = System.DateTime.ParseExact( record.TimeWhen, myFormat, null );
        mySpan = myDateTime.Subtract( originTime );
        value = mySpan.TotalSeconds;
        seconds = ( float ) myDateTime;
        Debug.Print("{0}", value );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain better your question? What is your `foreach` statement supposed to do?

Comment: Sure.  I was learning C# with a for-loop and string-to-DateTime conversion (reading in vector of ISO 8601 time strings).  That's the posted code.  Just want to know how to use records.ToList to process all the string entries, each one to its DateTime value.

Comment: You are doing more than just converting text to a date but I am not sure what or why or what the problem is.

Comment: "I am sure that the ToList method of 'records' would allow me to convert all the string entries to DateTime values, but I cannot get there." -- "I cannot get there" is not a question. Please tell us what problem you are having, or at least ask a question. This is a question and answer site and you did not ask a single question. Judging from the answers, people were able to extract your actual question: "How do I create a list of my parsed DateTime's? I think I can use `ToList()` somehow, but I have no clue where" -- ask that directly and we can help you better instead of deciphering intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from a list of some type `A` to a list of type `B`, I suggest you to use `Linq` `Select()` method

```
using system.Linq;

IEnumerable<DataRecord1> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord1>();
List<DateTime> datetimes = records.Select(x => System.DateTime.ParseExact(x.TimeWhen, myFormat, null).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe you are missing a parenthesis ")" after the null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to do that

```
var l = records
    .Select(x=>System.DateTime.ParseExact(x.TimeWhen, myFormat, null))
    .Select(x=>x.Subtract(originTime))
    .Select(x=>mySpan.TotalSeconds)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using linq, you could use Extension methods to do that:

```cs
public static DateTime ToDateTime(this DataRecord1, format)
{
    return System.DateTime.ParseExact(DataRecord1.TimeWhen, format);
}
```

and them, call the ToDateTime method:

```cs
IEnumerable<DataRecord1> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord1>();
List<DateTime> datetimes = new List<DateTime>();
records.ForEach(x => datetimes.Add(x.ToDateTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

From signature your CsvReader is returning an IEnumerable. It is up to you to convert it to a list or not. For DateTime conversion I would use TryParse. ie:

```
var originTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
IEnumerable<DataRecord1> records;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.csv"))
{
    var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
    records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord1>();
}

DateTime t;
var result = from r in records
             let sWhen = r.TimeWhen
             let When = DateTime.TryParse(sWhen, out t) ? t : (DateTime?)null
             let span = When - originTime
             let Epoch = span.HasValue ? span.Value.TotalSeconds : (double?)null
             select new
             {
                 sWhen,
                 When,
                 Epoch
             };

// result.Take(5).ToList()
```